# how to remove the radio button focus on previous selected item in spinner

Tags: android, radio-button, android-spinner

I have created the spinner which have items in Telugu font.
I am displaying the Telugu font using ttf files. And I am overriding the array adapter view method and drop down view method for displaying the items in Telugu. but my problem is the default selection is on first item. But if I select the third item, the radio button focus is still on the first item. So how to resolve that? I have a view and drop down method like this.

And the get view and dropdown view is for getting the spinner element text in telugu. I have declared spinner elements as string array which contains text in telugu.

```
final ArrayAdapter<String> cropAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, cropElements) {
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

            Typeface externalFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
                    "DroidSansRegionalAAD.ttf");
            ((TextView) v).setTypeface(externalFont);
            return v;
        }

        public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView,
                ViewGroup parent) {
            View v = super.getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent);

            Typeface externalFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
                    "DroidSansRegionalAAD.ttf");
            ((TextView) v).setTypeface(externalFont);

            return v;

        };

    };
    cropAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
```

Comment: See in [this tutorial,](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-spinner-drop-down-list-example/) the first item is doesn't contain any `RadioButton` You can try like this.

Comment: i have seen this. i have practiced that example it. that wrks fine. but i am not getting this properly. i am getting this problem from when i used ttf file for displaying the text in telugu.

Comment: Hi. Have you solved it? I have very similar problem. I don't want focus on last selected item but on first item

Comment: yes. that is because of i have added the font in oncreate() and also in getview and getDropdown view also. so i have removed the applying fornt in those twi methods. it works fine now